# How to put a line indicator in a pie / doughnut chart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck with this UI thing. I usually use with FL_charts, but I'm stuck over 1 thing:  Can't figure out how to put a red line for the Class average.

[image]

I am using fl_charts is there any option to do thi?.

Answer (score 0):

In fl_chart, which is a powerful Flutter chart library, there isn't a built-in specific feature for adding a line indicator like the one you've shown in the image. However, you can achieve this by customizing the ExtraLinesData within the PieChartData or DoughnutChartData.

Here's an example of how you might add an extra line to a pie chart using fl_chart:

```
PieChartData(
      centerSpaceRadius: 0,
      sections: yourSections, // your list of PieChartSectionData
      extraLinesData: ExtraLinesData(
        extraLinesOnTop: false, // Set it to false so the lines are drawn below the sections
        showingLines: [
          HorizontalLine(
            y: classAverageY, // This needs to be the percentage of the class average
            color: const Color(0xffc72c41),
            strokeWidth: 2,
            dashArray: [5, 10], // Custom dash pattern for your line
            label: HorizontalLineLabel(
              show: true,
              labelResolver: (line) => 'Class Average',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: line.color,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.topRight, // Position of the label
              margin: 8, // Margin from the right end
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Note that HorizontalLine is used for adding horizontal lines in bar charts, and for a pie/doughnut chart, this concept doesn't directly apply. So you'd have to adapt it. You may need to create a custom widget overlay or a way to position your line and text properly on top of the chart. If fl_chart does not support the exact feature you need, you could also consider using a Stack widget to overlay custom Flutter drawing primitives on top of the chart.